# What is this coat of arms for J. Schneller?

Tags: identification, heraldry

I found this coat of arms on old piano notes.

[image: Round seal, in annulo "J. Johannes Schneller", within an indistinct coat of arms that has in base three roundels]

What is this coat of arms?

Comment: Is this the best quality image you can get? A lot of detail is lost (or, at least, unclear) in the supplied picture.

Comment: No, this is the best quality in this case.

Comment: There are several Johannes Schneller from Felsberg (Switzerland). Do you know if the notes you found were swiss-related? Any language related to Switzerland?

Comment: no, I found it on piano notes.

Comment: It's possible this is an "ex libris" stamp meant to identify the owner. This wouldn't be regulated by any heraldic authority - they could put whatever they wanted on it. My great grandfather did the same thing and made up a cool looking coat of arms for his.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an answer, but perhaps the following might be a clue for someone else's research.

If I'm reading the [hatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatching_(heraldry)) correctly:

- The top contains dots, which would indicate that it should be  *or* (gold).
- The bottom is hatched with horizontal lines, which indicate *azure* (blue).
- There are three [roundels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundel_(heraldry)) (circles).  My initial read is that the are all solid, but it is possible that the top two are hollow.  based on what little I know of heraldry, I suspect that they are all solid and the appearance of hollow is a result of poor image quality or poor ink transfer.
- Assuming that the base is *azure*, the roundels would need to be either *or* or *argent*
- Initially I thought the roundels were "in base", but based on other evidence, i wonder if the field *party per fess*

The [Schneller](https://coatofarmsgifts.com/products/schneller-coat-of-arms-download) crest is quite similar. The name is the same and the colors match. But on the other hand, [Schneller](https://coatofarmsgifts.com/products/schneller-coat-of-arms-download) has 4 roundels. and appears to be party per fess.

It is possible, but unlikely that the charge in chief in OP's arms is the same as [Schneller](https://coatofarmsgifts.com/products/schneller-coat-of-arms-download).